# Python Broadcasting: Use 1D vector as index in one dimension of 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

Suppose I have a 2D array, `table` of shape `m x n`.

Suppose I have a 1D array, `col_indices` of shape `m`, and range `[0,n)` in terms of the values.

Finally, suppose I have a value array, `vals` of shape `u`, indexed by `i`.

---

In pseudo code, I would like to write:

```
table[:,col_ind[:]] += vals[i]
```

And, written out manually:

```
t = [ [ 0,0,0]
      [ 0,0,0]
      [ 0,0,0] ]

c = [ 0, 1, 2 ]

v = [ 1, 10, 1000 ]

i = 1

# then f(t,c,v,i) where f is the broadcast function
f(t,c,v,i) outputs:

t = [ [ 10,  0,  0 ]
      [  0, 10,  0 ]
      [  0,  0, 10 ] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) by replacing the row slice with an integer array:

```
t[np.arange(c.size), c] = v[i]

t
#array([[10,  0,  0],
#       [ 0, 10,  0],
#       [ 0,  0, 10]])
```